# How to read a character from the dos window?

Tags: assembly

I want to know how to read and store a character from the dos window in Assembly. I know int 21h is used to print something, but I want the opposite to happen. Lets say I have this written:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

I already have the x,y points of two characters, I just want to replace between them, for example, replace 0,0 (1) with 3,1 (3). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, found a solution for myself..

```
mov ah, 08h
int 10h
```

Then, character is saved in parameter AL.

Comment: Please note that this BIOS function also returns the attribute in AH. The function moreover requires you to provide the videopage number in BH. (mostly set it to 0)